# bigr dataframe error 'do not know how to convert 'df$V3' to class “POSIXct”'

Tags: r, biginsights, bigr

I'm trying to create a calculated column with bigr.  First load the data:

```
> df <- bigr.frame (dataPath = "/data.csv", 
                    dataSource="DEL", delimiter=",", header=F,
                    coltypes = c("integer", "character", "character"))
```

Then attempt to add a column:

```
> df$posixct = as.POSIXct(df$V3, tz="UTC", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

However, I get the error message:

```
Error in as.POSIXct.default(df$V3, tz = "UTC", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") : 
  do not know how to convert 'df$V3' to class “POSIXct”
```

I've taken a look at the class:

```
> class(df$V3)
[1] "bigr.vector"
attr(,"package")
[1] "bigr"
```

The values in the V3 column look like this:

```
2005-01-01 00:00:00
2005-01-01 00:10:00
...
```

I'm not sure how to proceed - any tips?

---

Update:

I've tried converting to a character:

```
> df$posixct = as.POSIXct(
                   as.character(df$V3), tz="UTC", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

But receive the following error

```
Error in as.POSIXct.default(as.character(df$V3), tz = "UTC", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") : 
  do not know how to convert 'as.character(df$V3)' to class “POSIXct”
```

Comment: There appears to be no method to convert `bigr.vector` to POSIX. Try coercing it to character.

Comment: I just tried and added the output

Comment: Try coercing outside the `as.POSIXct`. A reproducible example would make things much more expedient.